# How to pass a variable from a Node.js file to a frontend JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I would like to know how to pass the "myBlogs" variable that I have in my Node.js file ("server.js") to a frontend JavaScript file ("blogs.js"). Once I have access to it in the JS file, I would then map through the array that is stored in that variable and output a template for each blog in an HTML file ("blogs.html").

Later, the idea is to get the blogs data from a database (MongoDB) instead of having them hard coded. I have seen how to do this with Express and a templating engine (EJS), but as practice for a beginner, I would like to understand the basics of if and how it can be done without these tools.

My file structure:

```
blogs.css
blogs.html
blogs.js
server.js
```

server.js:

```
const http = require("http");
const fs = require("fs");
const myBlogs = [
  {
    title: "My first blog",
    author: "John",
  },
  {
    title: "My second blog",
    author: "Mike",
  },
];

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  console.log("request made");

  // set header content type
  let path = "";
  switch (req.url) {
    case "/blogs.css":
      path += "blogs.css";
      res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/css");
      break;
    case "/blogs.js":
      path += "blogs.js";
      res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/javascript");
      break;
    default:
      path += "blogs.html";
      res.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/html");
  }

  // send file
  fs.readFile(path, (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.end();
    } else {
      res.write(data);
      res.end();
    }
  });
});

server.listen(3000, "localhost", () => {
  console.log("listening for requests on port 3000");
});
```

blogs.js:

```
const container = document.querySelector("div")


const html = myBlogs.map(blog => (
    `<h2>${blog.title}</h2>
    <p>${blog.author}</p>`
))
container.innerHTML = html;
```

blogs.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="blogs.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div></div>

    <script src="blogs.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

blogs.css:

```
p {
    color: red;
}
```

P.S.: If such an approach is completely wrong, could you please explain the correct way this would be done without the use of Express and a templating engine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

server.js

```js
  // send file
  fs.readFile(path, "utf8", (err, data) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
      res.end();
    } else {
      res.write(data.replace(/%MY_BLOGS%/g, JSON.stringify(myBlogs)));
      res.end();
    }
  });
```

blogs.html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="blogs.css" />
    <script>
       var myBlogs = %MY_BLOGS%;
       console.log(myBlogs);
    </script>

  </head>
  <body>
    <div></div>

    <script src="blogs.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is incredibly hacky and not a good practice at all. It basically just finds %MY_BLOGS% and interpolates a JSON encoded object. Since JSON is valid JS, it will be directly accessible in your client side JS. You can now access `myBlogs` in blogs.js since it's a global variable.

Comment: I don't think it's hacky. I would even say it's a common way. But I would prefer a template engine.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried this code, but am getting the following error:

 res.write(data.replace(/%MY_BLOGS%/g, JSON.stringify(myBlogs)));
                       ^
TypeError: data.replace is not a function
at FSReqCallback.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (node:internal/fs/read_file_context:68:3)

Can you please advise how to fix it? Thanks

Comment: @Hvalur123 Sorry, I forgot to add the utf8 encoding to the readFile call. I updated my answer. Data was returning a Buffer instead of a string hence why replace didn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `HTTP` you could use something like `express.js` with `ejs` to pass backend data to front end.

```
npm i express ejs
```

Now you have `express.js` and `ejs` installed write some simple code like this:

server.js

```
const express = require('express')
// Create new server
const app = express()

// This will read read all the files in static and add them eg;
// static/style.css would now be able to do localhost:3000/style.css
app.use(express.static("static"))
// Set the view engine from text to ejs
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')


// app.get means you are using the get method on the url "/"
app.get('/', (req,res) => {
  // res.render is the method for ejs
  // res.render(file, options)
  res.render('blogs', {
    // Now on the front end you would be able to get data
    data: example
  })
})

// Start listening on X port
app.listen(3000, () => { 
  console.log("Listening on port 3000")
})
```

views/blogs.ejs

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="blogs.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>My blogs <%= locals.data %></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

In `ejs` you use `<% %>` to run something and `<%= %>` to output something

Your project structure would look something like this:

```
static
  blogs.css
  blogs.js
views
  blogs.ejs

server.js
```

You should read up on `express.js` and `ejs`

Comment: OP specifically said he/she **doesn't** want to use EJS and express "I have seen how to do this with Express and a templating engine (EJS), but as practice for a beginner, I would like to understand the basics of if and how it can be done without these tools."